# openvpn - iptables or nftables

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Iptables has been around for a long time, but nftables seems to be picking up steam. I've noticed in newer distributions of Kubernetes images (aws, etc) no longer have the iptables kernel module baked into them. I run Openvpn from a kubernetes pod, and as the underlying host's kernel doesn't have the iptables kernel module baked into it, i'd have to do my own custom image.

I'm trying to debate whether I should make the leap now towards nftables or continue to stick with iptables. I'm finding however that most documentation (like the ones here on openvpn.net) don't make any reference to nftables, but iptables. i also find far fewer sites on the internet discussing nftables with openvpn.

should i migrate to nftables or stick to what appears to be tried and true with openvpn, which is iptables?

what is the future of iptables?

what would/do you do?

Comment: It's pretty common for distributions to use a version of the `iptables` command that actually talks to `nftables` on the backend. You could presumably use the same thing in your image.